# Reload previous screen in React Native

Tags: react-native, navigation, reload

I've been using this way to refresh the previous screen when triggering a button from the current screen.

**Screen A**

```
constructor(props){
  ...
  this.handleOnNavigateBack = this.handleOnNavigateBack.bind(this);
}

handleOnNavigateBack = (foo) => {
  this.setState({ foo })
}

goToScreenB(){
  this.props.navigation.navigate('ScreenB', {
    onNavigateBack: this.handleOnNavigateBack
  })
}
```

**Screen B**

```
goBackToScreenA(){
  this.props.navigation.state.params.onNavigateBack(this.state.foo)
  this.props.navigation.goBack()
}
```

I need to keep the function inside the parameters first so that it can be triggered when going back from screen b. But this is okay to use if it is from 1 screen to 1 screen. If I have a multi layer screen been navigated such as

from **Screen A -> Screen B -> Screen C**,

and go back

from **Screen C -> Screen B -> Screen A** then reload the function at Screen A, it will be troublesome.

Or maybe the situation is :

from **Screen A -> Screen B**, then from **Screen B replace Screen C**, then from **Screen C -> Screen A** then only reload the function at Screen A.

By doing so, I have to keep passing the function to reload when every navigation taken place. So I was wondering if there is a way to capture the screen entered and fire the specific function that you want like how **Ionic** did.

In Ionic case, there is an event called `ionViewWillEnter` where it helps to perform this reloading thing without going through with the function registration and all. You simply call out the function and that's it.

I've been trying to find a way that is working similar to this at React Native but I can't have it work around. I've heard about redux but never implement it as I still can't understand how it works so I'm trying not to use it first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your question you are looking for something similar to 'ionViewWillEnter' which will run a callback whenever a screen is focused.

Given that you are using React Navigation v5
The hook useFocusEffect serves the same purpose of running a function whenever a screen is focused this includes navigating back to a screen as well.

From the documentation

> Sometimes we want to run side-effects when a screen is focused. A side
> effect may involve things like adding an event listener, fetching
> data, updating document title, etc. While this can be achieved using
> focus and blur events, it's not very ergonomic.

The code would be something like this

```
  useFocusEffect(
    React.useCallback(() => {
      alert('Screen focused')
      // Do something when the screen is focused
      return () => {
        alert('Screen was unfocused');
        // Do something when the screen is unfocused
        // Useful for cleanup functions
      };
    }, [])
  );
```

You can find the documentation here
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/use-focus-effect/

If your requirement is updating the data by passing something from screen B or C you can think of using Context which is easy to use or if you are planning to to use redux that is also a possible alternative.

Comment: Thanks for the info! I didn't notice this. It seems like there are a lot of works need to do since I'm still using `static navigationOptions` although I am using v5. And I figured out that the screen doesn't trigger anything within it.

Comment: I dont think navigationOptions  are supported in V5, the replacement is setoptions